# SWF - Sending input parameters to workflow

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have a SWF workflow decider to which I need to pass a set of values. I already have a class (POJO) which has all these as instance variables. So should I pass the POJO as input parameter or pass the individual fields.

```
@Workflow
@@WorkflowRegistrationOptions(....)
public interface WorkerClass {

   @Execute(version = "1.0")
   void generate(String a, int b, List<String> c, String d);
}

or
  void generate(POJO pojo);
```

where POJO is

```
class POJO {
    private String a;
    private int b; 
    private List<String> c;
    private String d;
    //Getter and setters
}
```

Which is best?

P.S : I need to run this from SWF console

Answer (score 1):

As a general design pattern I prefer passing POJO for initialization as adding fields to it is backwards compatible. AWS Flow Framework supports both approaches. By default it uses [JsonDataConverter](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/JsonDataConverter.java) to serialize function parameters. You can always write your own that parses workflow input string field into your POJO structure (and specifying it at @Workflow annotation) or specify parameters in the way that JSON converter expects. The easiest way to learn about the default format is to start workflow using generated external client and then look at the input field from the workflow [WorkflowExecutionStartedEvent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_WorkflowExecutionStartedEventAttributes.html).